# Spring validation in non MVC application

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

Is this possible to validate POJO class in similiar way to that how it is done in MVC controller in non-MVC application?

For example:

```
public class Form {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 25)
    private String login;
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
Form f = new Form();
f.setLogin("login");
```

And now I would like to pass it to some kind of validator which will test all fields based on their annotations just like @Valid does in MVC.

Note that I want to validate fields by their annotations. I don't want to write all validation conditions such if (login.lenght() < 4 && ....

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Hibernate Validator, it's an implementation of the Java Bean Validation specification - works in JDK environment (no JEE) as described [here](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)

Hibernate Validator allows you to add annotations and then run validation based on that annotations with something like this:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations =
  validator.validate(objectToValidate);
```

You can then check the constraintViolations collection for errors.